# Feature-flag based authorization with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I am trying to roll out authorization in an entire environment and would like to feature flag this for quick rollback if it goes south. Once we know all services are aligned with OAuth this feature will be removed and become permanent. I have chosen the `IAutofacAuthorizationFilter` to inject an object to determine the feature flag state which a [typical attribute doesn't offer](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#standard-web-api-filter-attributes-are-singletons).

I'd like to enable the default behavior as if I had decorated the controller with `[Authorize]` if the feature is true otherwise let the methods execute without it, but I'm having trouble enabling the default behavior from inside a `IAutofacAuthorizationFilter` where there is no base class to override like `await base.OnAuthorizationAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);` inside a `AuthorizeAttribute`.

What I have working so far:

```
public class FeatureBasedAuthorizeAttribute : IAutofacAuthorizationFilter
{
     private readonly IFeatureManager _featureManager;

     public FeatureBasedAuthorizeAttribute(IFeatureManager featureManager)
     {
          _featureManager = featureManager;
     }

     public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
          if (_featureManager.IsEnabled<EnableAppAuthorization>())
          {
               // Return result of default ASP.Net authorization here... How?
          }
          // Return without Authorization (current state)
          await Task.FromResult(0);
     }
}

// Wire up in startup.cs
builder.Register(c => new FeatureBasedAuthorizeAttribute(c.Resolve<IFeatureManager>()))
                .AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterForAllControllers()
                .InstancePerRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately time away from the screen solved it for me. My solution was this:

```
public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     if (_featureManager.IsEnabled<EnableAppAuthorization>())
     {
          // Return result of default ASP.Net authorization
          var authorizeAttribute = new AuthorizeAttribute();
          await authorizeAttribute.OnAuthorizationAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
     }
     // Return without Authorization (current state)
     await Task.FromResult(0);
}
```